# Does a compact set in the interior of a cone also belong to the intersection of all slightly perturbed cones?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

Suppose compact set $S \subseteq R^n$ is in the interior of $x_0+C$, where $C$ denotes a solid convex cone in $R^n$ with the vertex at $0$. I am trying to prove that $\exists r>0$ such that
$$S \subseteq \bigcap_{x \in B_r(x_0)} (x+C),$$
where $B_r(x_0)$ denotes the open ball with radius $r$ and center $x_0$. I am not sure where to get started… Should I calculate the distance of $S$ to the border of the cone $x_0+C$ and use this distance to find a suitable $r$?

Comment: Do you just need to show that there exists an $r > 0$ for which this is true?

Comment: Yes, @Brian Tung , I just need to show that such $r>0$ exists.

Comment: Actually, I thought a bit more about this and think that I can prove this by contradiction e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with cones. WLOG, $x_0=0.$ The result follows from this more general result: Suppose $K\subset U,$ with $K$ compact and $U$ open. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $K\subset U+x$ for all $x\in B_r(0).$

Proof: If $U=\mathbb {R}^n,$ the result is obvious. If not, then $U^c$ is nonempty. Because $K,U^c$ are disjoint, $K$ is compact and $U^c$ is closed, we have $d(K,U^c)=r>0.$ Let $x\in B_r(0).$ If $y\in K,$ then $y+x \in U.$ Thus $K+x \subset U,$ which is the same as saying $K \subset U - x.$ Because the map $x\to -x$ leaves $B_r(0)$ unchanged, we see

$$K \subset U + x \ \text {for all}\ x \in B_r(0).$$